# Determination of an integer

Tags: analysis, inequality

I got a problem. I don't know how to solve this kind of problem:

Find an integer $n_0$ that for each $n>n_0$ this inequation would be always true:

$$\dfrac{n^{4}-n^{2}+1}{n^{3}-n}>10000 $$

I don't know how to solve this kind of problems, and I hope you could help me understanding how to proceed step by step. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, do you have any idea why such a number is guaranteed to exist? If so, then use that idea. If not, then look at the most significant terms in those two polynomials, and think about what happens when $n$ gets large.

Comment: Finding any integer $n_0$ where the inequality is true, that is easy. Finding the smallest integer requires only slightly more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$\dfrac{n^{4}-n^{2}+1}{n^{3}-n}>10000\Leftrightarrow n+\dfrac{1}{n^{3}-n}>10000
$

$0<\dfrac{1}{n^{3}-n}<1\Leftrightarrow n>1$

Comment: Thank you so much. i would like to know if this method is right as well:

(n^3-n)/(n^4-n^2+1) < (n^3-n)/n^4 < n^3/n^4 < 1/10000

Solving this n > 10000

Comment: The majoration

$\frac{n^{3}-n}{n^{4}-n^{2}+1}<\frac{n^{3}-n}{n^{4}}$

is not correct ($n^{4}-n^{2}+1<n^{4}$)

Comment: Yes right! what about (n^3 - n )/(n ^4 -2n^2) <  (n^3)/((n^2)(n^2-2)) and the result would be  (n^2-2)/n  >  10000

Comment: It is a possible valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

Can you divide out the fraction to a polynomial and remainder?  That will help.